# Report on Account with their Opportunities

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, joined-reports

I have a requirement where i have one parent account and that account has many child accounts and their opportunities. The Account Owner of the Parent account needs to be able to report out a summary of all of the details and activity which has happened on all accounts and opportunities underneath their Parent Account, by account hierarchy. Is it possible by using joined report?
Please help.

Thanks,
Sanjana

Answer (score 0):

If I got your requirements right you indeed can use a joined report and 2 standard report types: Opportunities and Tasks and Events.

[image]

Once in the Report Builder group them by the Parent Account. Set other filters for more granular control over what you want to display.

This is a simple approach, it may bring some value for analysis though. If you need something complex, consider creating custom report types (with lookup fields if necessary) and build reports based off them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new Report Type for it.
From **SetUp**--> **Report Type**.
In that Select Primary Object as a "**Account**" and in Step 2, select child object (B) select "**Opportunity**" and in "**A to B Relationships**" select **2nd** Option(**A records may or may not**....). And In **"C"** select **Activity** Object

Create new report with new Report Type and **Group by a row** using **Parent Account Name and Account Name**